# Line drawing not showing on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a simple line on  but it doesn't work on the page.  I have placed my JavaScript in several places on the html page, but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Thank you

**My JavaScript code:**

```
function drawLine() {


var c = document.getElementById("line");
var draw = c.getContext("2d");

draw.beginPath();
draw.lineWidth("5");
draw.strokeStyle("blue");
draw.moveTo(0, 75);
draw.lineTo(0, 75);
draw.stroke();

}
```

**My Html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<script type="text/javascript" src="vhw.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="vhw.js"></script>

<!-- INTRODUCTION -->

<div>

  <h1 class="intro">
    Line
  </h1>

</div>

<!-- LINE CODE -->

<div class="space">
  <canvas id="line" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px dotted #990099;    display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" onload="drawLine()">
  </canvas>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

call drawLine methode from onload of window not from canvas element :

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
drawLine();
}
```

and your html code like this :

```
<div class="space">
  <canvas id="line" width="300" height="150" style="border: 2px dotted #990099;    
   display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" >
  </canvas>
 </div>
```

also your drawLine :

```
function drawLine() {
    var canevas = document.getElementById('line');
    if (canevas.getContext) {
       var c = document.getElementById("line");
       var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
       ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
       ctx.stroke();
      }
}
```